# gammu-smsd SQL Query Customization

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, gammu

I've a Problem with the gammu smsd-daemon. I wan't to customize some mysql querys to write something into my database.

I found this
http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/sql.html#gammu-smsd-sql

So I added this line to my config:

`[sql]`

`refresh_phone_state = "UPDATE`state`set`signal`='%2',`battery`='%1' WHERE`id`='1'"`

Then I killed all smsd Instances and restarted the smsd-daemon but the refresh_phone_state is always the same, my table state is never touched:

`May 24 18:43:01 debian gammu-smsd[2567]: Execute SQL: UPDATE`phones`SET`TimeOut`= (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND)+0,`Battery`= 0,`Signal`= 57 WHERE`IMEI`= '354483029016862'`

My config file is this:
http://pastie.org/pastes/3961819/text?key=kbkpmkalyybediaqxfb1a

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the Problem, I used gammu from the Debian Stable, so I had an older Version.

customization of the sql querys is since this version: `20101202 - 1.28.93`